# Excel cell from which a Function is called

Tags: excel, vba, cell

How can I get the cell where my VBA Function is called from?

In other words, what is the VBA equivalent for INDIRECT(ROW(), COLUMN()) ?

I'm *not* looking for **ActiveCell**.

What I want to do is have a simple function `ThisRow_Col(rColumn As String)` return the column X of the row it's called from. Say in B2 I call =ThisRow_Col("A"), it should return the value of A2. This should work regardless of which cell active.

**EDIT**: Thanks Charles for the answer: **Application.Caller**. The following code gets the column X of the current row, independent of where the selection is:

```
Function ThisRow_Col(rColumn As Range)
    ' Return INDIRECT(rcolumn & ROW())

    ThisRow_Col = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Cells(Application.Caller.Row, rColumn.Column).Value

End Function
```

Note that passing the column as a Range (`ThisRow_Col(A1)`) is better than passing it as a string, because Excel can automatically update the formulas if you move or insert columns. Of course the `1` row of `A1` is just a convention.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`Application.Caller` returns the range object that the UDF is called from.

Comment: @dandv, @phoog, Here is some more detail about Application.Caller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861431/vba-how-to-get-the-last-used-cell-by-vba-code-when-the-last-error-occured-in-a-w/3874340#3874340