# Consistently returning the entire array in a VBA UDF?

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I've written the following simple VBA function to calculate linear progression between two amounts for some amount of intervals and return the progression as an array:

```
Public Function applyLinear(startAmount As Double, stopAmount As Double, Intervals As Integer)
    Dim diff As Double
    Dim resultArr() As Double
    Dim counter As Integer    
    diff = stopAmount - startAmount
    ReDim resultArr(Intervals, 0)
    resultArr(0, 0) = startAmount
    For counter = 1 To (Intervals)
        resultArr(counter, 0) = resultArr(counter - 1, 0) + diff / Intervals
    Next ' counter
    counter = 0
    applyLinear = resultArr
End Function
```

Unfortunately, what actually gets outputted to the worksheet **depends entirely on how many cells the above formula is called from.** (This means that it becomes laughably easy for a user to apply the function incorrectly!)

How can I ensure that the **entire** array is outputted to the worksheet under **all** circumstances?

Edit: Or rather, more specifically, how can I get VBA to output the entire array when calling the above UDF from a single cell?

Edit 2: Some more clarification. The function does work as intended if "intervals+1" rows are used when calling it. A problem arises however, if (for example) the user accidentally calls the function from 4 rows when intervals is > 4. In this case only the first four elements of resultArr are outputted to the worksheet, this is an issue because it doesn't represent the full linear progression.

Comment: Did you try setting your variables to zero at the beginning of your udf?

Comment: @ Tom. I don't quite follow? The function does work as intended, but only if the user calls the function from "intervals+1" cells.

Comment: Perhaps add a check to see whether the range that the UDF has been entered in = "intervals + 1". Then instead of inputting a value, make the UDF read something like "ERROR - MUST ENTER IN " & "Interval +1" " CELLS INSTEAD OF " & #OF_CELLS_ENTERED

Comment: @ Grade 'Eh' Bacon - That's definitely an option, at least the user won't be misled! Ideally though I'm holding out for some way to get it to work with one 'input cell'. I suspect there is some kind of mystical VBA workaround to do this, since Bloomberg seems to have managed it in their Excel add-in.

Comment: Take a look at my suggestion below; I've tried to solve both ways - by changing the value based on number of cells entered, or simply showing an error message when the wrong # of cells are entered. If I've misinterpreted how many cells need to be entered (Intervals? Or Intervals+1?), then that should be an easy fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking into how to do what I suggested in the comment above, I found some interesting info on the Application.Caller function, which allows you to access the properties of the cell a UDF is entered in. See here: [Excel cell from which a Function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5559279/5090027)

Here's one way to do this, based on a little bit of further guidance from cpearson [http://www.cpearson.com/excel/returningarraysfromvba.aspx]

```
Public Function applyLinear(startAmount As Double, stopAmount As Double, Intervals As Integer)

Dim diff As Double
Dim resultArr() As Double
Dim counter As Integer
ReDim resultArr(Intervals, 0)

If Application.Caller.Rows.Count <> Intervals + 1 Then

    applyLinear = "ERROR - MUST ENTER THIS FORMULA IN " & Intervals + 1 & " CELLS"

Else

    diff = stopAmount - startAmount
    resultArr(0, 0) = startAmount

    For counter = 1 To (Intervals)
        resultArr(counter, 0) = resultArr(counter - 1, 0) + diff / Intervals
        TotalityCheck = TotalityCheck + resultArr(counter, 0) 'builds in by the end of the loop the total array value
    Next ' counter


    applyLinear = resultArr
End If

End Function
```

Although, now that you have the use of the Application.Caller function, you could perhaps do this a little more simply, by removing the need for the user to enter the number of Intervals - instead, define the number of intervals as the application.caller.rows - 1, as follows:

```
Public Function applyLinear(startAmount As Double, stopAmount As Double)

Dim diff As Double
Dim resultArr() As Double
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Intervals As Integer
ReDim resultArr(Intervals, 0)

Intervals = Application.Caller.Rows.Count - 1

    diff = stopAmount - startAmount
    resultArr(0, 0) = startAmount

    For counter = 1 To (Intervals)
        resultArr(counter, 0) = resultArr(counter - 1, 0) + diff / Intervals
        TotalityCheck = TotalityCheck + resultArr(counter, 0) 'builds in by the end of the loop the total array value
    Next ' counter


    applyLinear = resultArr


End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably go use this version without intervals as a parameter. Just had to shift the ReDim down and it works like a charm.