# VBA function for excel that returns the Row value for the cell you put the function in as an integer?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a custom function that requires both the Row of the function and the row below it as integers to be used in that function. I tried

```
Function Row()  
Row = worksheetfunction.excel.row()
End Function
```

However that returns #Value! in excel. 
I hope the problem is that I just don't know the syntax to identify the cell I'm putting the formula in and I can use the built in excel row function to get the result.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow zeBeowulf. Your question seems to be related to the question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559279/excel-cell-from-which-a-function-is-called). Use `Application.Caller` as mentioned in the related answer.

Comment: or `Application.ThisCell`

Answer (score 1):

```
Function UDF()
    Dim theRow As Long
    '// Application.Caller is Range
    theRow = Application.Caller.Row
End Function
```